# Sensor size of Sony HDR-HC7e

Tags: camera, opencv

I want to motion track a shot from my Sony HDR-HC7e camcorder and I am not quite sure about the horizontal sensor size(width).
I set the focal length to minimum and the recording to HDV 16:9

[This](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/res/manuals/2319/23198061M.pdf) manual (HC7e and HC7 are basically the same) states it is a 1/2.9" sensor with a diagonal of 6.3mm (page 101). But if I do my calculations and multiply (1/2.9) with 25.4 to convert it to mm I get 8.75862069?

The camcorder outputs a 1440*1080 interlaced .m2t file. The image in this file is squeezed by a factor of 1.33. as seen in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2AvN.jpg).
So I suppose that the sensor has an aspect ratio of 4/3(1.33) So I did some math:

---

$$a^2 = b^2 +c^2$$

$$
\begin{matrix}
a_1 &=& 6.3\\
a_2 &=& 8.75862069\\
b &=& x\\
c &=& 1.33x\\
\end{matrix}
$$

---

$$6.3^2 = x^2 + (1.33x)^2$$

$$
\begin{matrix}
x &=& 3.78605\\
1.33x &=& 5.0354465\\
\textrm{horizontal 1} &=& 5.0354465
\end{matrix}
$$

---

$$8.75862069^2 = x^2 + (1.33x)^2$$

$$
\begin{matrix}
x &=& 5.26359\\
1.33x &=& 7.0005747\\
\textrm{horizontal 2} &=& 7.0005747\\
\end{matrix}
$$

So I thought because there always is a relation between sensor size and focal length, I just take the sensor size horizontal 35mm and the corresponding 35mm focal length equivalent of 49mm (manual page 101) and get the ration: 35 / 49 = 0.714285714 then multiply the true focal length of 5.4mm by that and get a horizontal sensor size of 3.857142856

So now I have got 3 possible horizontal sensor sizes. Now I want to calibrate my lens with a set of images like the linked one. Should I leave them with the 1.33 aspect ratio and where would I specify that in the OpenCV camera calibration or do I unsqueze them and then calibrate? And do I even need the sensor size and focal length for OpenCV camera calibration?

Comment: You might have a better time asking about this on [Photography.SE](photo.stackexchange.com), I'd guess they will know more about camera sensor geometry. This is a bit out of our bailiwick here at CGSE.

Answer (score 0):

Answer over in Photography:
https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119761/sensor-size-of-sony-hdr-hc7e/119764#119764
It turns out to be Vertical: 3.74 horizontal 4.98 and diagonal 6.23